# How validate confirm password with vue/quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I write a code to connect to an application in vue/quasar/C#
I'm just begin with vue. And I don't understand how rules run.
I write this to check input is not empty for password/ConfimPassword

```
<q-form v-bind:submit="createUser"
            v-bind:reset="resetCreateUser"
            class="q-gutter-md"
            v-if="status==2"
            ref="frmCreateUser"
            autofocus>
         <q-input filled
                 v-model="loginData.password"
                 label="Votre mot de passe"
                 hint="Saisissez votre mot de passe"
                 v-bind:type="isPwd ? 'password' : ''"
                 lazy-rules
                 v-bind:rules="[ val => val && val.length > 0 || 'Saisissez votre mot de passe']"
                 ref="fldPasswordCreateUser"
                 data-vv-name="fldPasswordCreateUser">
            <template v-slot:append>
                <q-icon :name="isPwd ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'"
                        class="cursor-pointer"
                        v-on:click="isPwd = !isPwd"></q-icon>
            </template>
        </q-input>
        <q-input filled
                 v-model="loginData.passwordConfirm"
                 label="Confirmez votre mot de passe"
                 v-bind:type="isPwd ? 'password' : ''"
                 lazy-rules
                 v-bind:rules="[ val => val && val.length > 0 || 'Saisissez votre mot de passe']">
            <template v-slot:append>
                <q-icon :name="isPwd ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'"
                        class="cursor-pointer"
                        v-on:click="isPwd = !isPwd"></q-icon>
            </template>
        </q-input>
       ...
    </q-form>
```

I check on my method `if (this.loginData.password == this.loginData.passwordConfirm) {...`
But I want modify my v-bind:rules and display error like empty field and put 'Password not match'
But I have always errors sysntaxs...
Thanks for your helps

### UPDATE

I try

```
v-bind:rules="[val => val && val.length > 0 || 'saisissez quelque chose :)',val => val != $refs.fldPasswordChange || 'Mots de passe différents']"
```

To have 2 controls but seems second not fire

### UPDATE2

I try what Dean suggest

```
 <q-input filled
                 v-model="loginData.password"
                 label="Votre mot de passe"
                 hint="Saisissez votre mot de passe"
                 v-bind:type="isPwd ? 'password' : ''"
                 lazy-rules
                 v-bind:rules="Required"
                 ref="fldPasswordChange">
            <template v-slot:append>
                <q-icon :name="isPwd ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'"
                        class="cursor-pointer"
                        v-on:click="isPwd = !isPwd"></q-icon>
            </template>
        </q-input>
        <q-input filled
                 v-model="loginData.passwordConfirm"
                 label="Confirmez votre mot de passe"
                 v-bind:type="isPwd ? 'password' : ''"
                 lazy-rules
                 v-bind:rules="ConfirmPWD"
                 ref="fldPasswordChangeConfirm">
            <template v-slot:append>
                <q-icon :name="isPwd ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'"
                        class="cursor-pointer"
                        v-on:click="isPwd = !isPwd"></q-icon>
            </template>
        </q-input>
```

and

```
 computed: {
            ConfirmPWD() {
                return [
                    (v) => !!v || "Saisissez quelquechose :-)",
                    (v) => v != this.$refs.fldPasswordChange.value || "Mots de passe différents"
                 ]
            },
            Required() {
                return [(v) => !!v || 'Saisissez quelque chose :-)']
            }
        },
```

But seems second controls not fire. If I don't fill confimPassword, i've message
but if I put 2 different password nothing..
I put breakpoint, all value is good. Cetainly a problem of syntax in my condition.. when I put

```
(v) => v != this.$refs.fldPasswordChange.value || "Mots de passe différents"
```

without  (v) => !!v || "Saisissez quelquechose :-)", no message error

Comment: I would recommend that you look into either 'computed' properties or 'filters' within the vue framework.  Any sort of complex logic can be cleaned up and managed more easily in a separate computed function that could return true or false if it meets your criteria. This would allow conditional labels or even disabled buttons when your password don't match. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<q-input filled
             v-model="loginData.password"
             label="Votre mot de passe"
             hint="Saisissez votre mot de passe"
             v-bind:type="isPwd ? 'password' : ''"
             lazy-rules
             v-bind:rules="Required"
             ref="fldPasswordChange">
        <template v-slot:append>
            <q-icon :name="isPwd ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'"
                    class="cursor-pointer"
                    v-on:click="isPwd = !isPwd"></q-icon>
        </template>
    </q-input>
    <q-input filled
             v-model="loginData.passwordConfirm"
             label="Confirmez votre mot de passe"
             v-bind:type="isPwd ? 'password' : ''"
             lazy-rules
             v-bind:rules="ConfirmPWD"
             ref="fldPasswordChangeConfirm">
        <template v-slot:append>
            <q-icon :name="isPwd ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'"
                    class="cursor-pointer"
                    v-on:click="isPwd = !isPwd"></q-icon>
        </template>
    </q-input>
```

and

```
computed: {
            ConfirmPWD() {
                return [
                    (v) => !!v || "Saisissez quelque chose :-)",
                    (v) => v == this.$refs.fldPasswordChange.value || "Mots de passe différents"
                 ]
            },
            Required() {
                return [(v) => !!v || 'Saisissez quelque chose :-)']
            }
        },
```

It's just a misunderstanding about first part... I need put good expression not condition to put error message.

Answer (score 5):

you can simply check this condition in rulles statement like this

> :rules="[val => val==loginData.password || 'Password is not matched']"